# Is it a good idea to install different versions of Sql Server on my laptop?

Tags: sql-server

I already have SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition on my laptop. One of the databases that we are using is SQL Server 2012. I can't modify the stored procedures. I have to log onto the server to use Management Studio 2012. It is kind of a pain. Is it worth putting a named instance on my local machine to use Management Studio 2012? What sort of problems might I run into?

Comment: As long as your laptop can handle it (disk space, RAM, CPU power) - no reason not to do it....

Comment: Have you though about installing SSDT for altering procedures rather than SSMS? It seems to be the way forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to install Management Studio 2012 on your local machine you can do that without having to add another instance.  Just start the install and select only the management tools when you get to the feature selection.

I'm actually doing it myself as I wanted to take advantage of some of the improvements in SSMS 2012.  We don't have any production servers running 2012 yet, but I still do all my SSMS work in the 2012 version even on the older servers.

To answer your core question however, putting a second instance of a different version is fully supported by SQL.  Microsoft doesn't have a [2012 version of this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210714%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) yet but the information is likely to be pretty much the same for gotcha's and things to keep in mind about side by side installs.

Comment: Just an FYI, you might want to go read the EULA for SQL 2012 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143522(v=sql.110).aspx). Generally on previous versions you are only allowed to use the SQL Server tools for the version you have licensed. So if you have SQL 2012 running in production, licensed, then you are allowed to use SQL 2012 management tools.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/7fcbd05f-326e-47f2-9283-48d93e72630e

Comment: I installed the management tools and it works great. Now that I installed that, I can open the 2012 databases in 2008 r2 and modify the stored procs and do the other things I couldn't before.